# Server-Sent Event with Jersey and weblogic

Tags: rest, server-sent-events, weblogic12c, jersey-2.0

I am experimenting with server sent event. Am following this link https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e8376. When I make request to the resource representing Server Sent Event, I get 500 Internal server error.

According to following error, I have to register the body writer for org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.EventOutput. But, how to do it?

```
####<21 Nov, 2013 3:17:28 PM IST> <Error> <com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse> <Laptop1> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '16' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <> <1385027248248> <BEA-000000> <Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.EventOutput, and Java type class org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.EventOutput, and MIME media type text/event-stream was not found
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:285)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1479)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at weblogic.jaxrs.server.portable.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:238)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3363)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3333)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2220)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2146)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2124)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1564)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
Caused By: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.EventOutput, and Java type class org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.EventOutput, and MIME media type text/event-stream was not found
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:285)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1479)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at weblogic.jaxrs.server.portable.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:238)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3363)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3333)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2220)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2146)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2124)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1564)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
```

> 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution for my own question.

To register SseFeature, getSingletons method should be overridden in Application derived class, as show in below code.

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    //....

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        Set<Object> singletons = super.getSingletons();
        if(singletons == null){
            singletons=new java.util.HashSet<Object>();
        }
        singletons.add(new SseFeature());
        return singletons;
    }

    //....

}
```

Comment: Old question but you just have to add the feature like this ```register(SseFeature.class)```

Answer (score 0):

to use jersey latest version ( jersey 2.8 ) we should get rid of com.sun.jersey.api
Jersey APIs are now in org.glassfish.jersey package.

I suggest you to go through the following post and resolve the issues
check the update in question and comments

[NoClassDefFoundError ProcessingException while migrating from jersey 1.x to jersey 2.x ( 2.8 )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23588678/noclassdeffounderror-processingexception-while-migrating-from-jersey-1-x-to-jers)