# NoClassDefFoundError ProcessingException while migrating from jersey 1.x to jersey 2.x ( 2.8 )

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, jersey-2.0

I developed a web service application which was working fine with jersey 1.x ( 1.16 )
I recently tried to migrate to latest stable jersey version 2.8

I deleted all jersey jar files of v1.16 
then I downloaded jersey jars of v2.8 from the link - https://jersey.java.net/download.html

As per documentation I came to know that, I should have latest servlet jar, servlet jar 2.5 or above, So I downloaded servlet-api-2.5.jar and added the same to /libs folder.

I downloaded javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m09.jar and added it to /libs
I also added latest jettison v 1.3.3 to /libs

But I am getting exception when I run on tomcat7 as follows
What are the exact steps to migrate from jersey 1.x to 2.x ? What is missing here ?

My Web.xml looks as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>com.tempWSJersey2.WebServices</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Temp REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
     <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
     <param-value>com.temp</param-value>
     </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Temp REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And the exception is  -

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/tempWSJersey2]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/tempWSJersey2]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/ProcessingException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2904)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2308)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1760)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:405)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5173)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 28 more

May 11, 2014 8:49:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:451)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more

May 11, 2014 8:49:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Catalina.start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:451)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

May 11, 2014 8:49:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1452 ms
```

If I include configuration class by extending ResourceConfig class
I get strange error as follows.

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The type javax.ws.rs.core.Configurable cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced 
     from required .class files
    - The hierarchy of the type AppConfiguration is inconsistent
```

Update - Solution to the problem 
1> Add all the jar files given jaxrs-ri folder which you download as jersey 2.8 from the link
https://jersey.java.net/download.html

Add jar files from all the folders , "lib", "ext", "api"

2> Add the jar files listed in the below post
[Can't enable POJO based JSON binding support for Jackson in Jersey 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511268/cant-enable-pojo-based-json-binding-support-for-jackson-in-jersey-2-0)

Now jersey 2.8 works perfectly ..

Comment: I tried with that, now I am getting different exception like
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/internal/ServletContainerProviderFactory
Could you please let me know the steps ? from beginning ? if possible with links to the appropriate jar files. The reason I am asking all steps is , I felt some thing seriously wrong, if I fix one issue , I get other issue.

Comment: Hi I applied your fix but later it was giving some other exception.
Then I came to know that I have to include all the jars that come with jersey framework. when we download it contains three folders Lib,ext, api, I should add jars from all these folder.

I was able to fix all,but when I run a simple welCome service, which is a GET method and returns JSON response as {"Status":"Welcome"} , It crashed and thrown a exception 

org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class
Any Idea on the same ?

Comment: See the update to answer. You need to add "org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs" provided if you are using jackson for json etc. If you are using something other than jackson you may have to add some other line as appropriate for that jar. I think this will fix your issue.

Comment: Did my last update to answer help you?

Comment: No vkg, It didn't help out., Instead I fixed exception by referring some other stackoverflow post. As per the post, I have to copy all the jar files from the downloaded jaxrs-ri folder. It has three folders within it, "lib", "ext" and "api" , I have to copy all the jar files from these three folders to my application lib folder. Then It fixed all the issues

Comment: Your original question was about this error. Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/ProcessingException. Which I guided you how to fix. I was kind of helping you out beyond your original question as well. You mean this answer was not helpful at all. :) But what you have described above it seems you are not using tools like maven or gradle or else you will not have to copy the jar one by one.

Comment: Finally found answer - please refer the post and add listed jars into your project to support jersey 2.8 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511268/cant-enable-pojo-based-json-binding-support-for-jackson-in-jersey-2-0

Comment: @vkg any idea on my another post ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23672354/server-side-event-not-firing-in-jersey-2-8-using-sse

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Exception you are getting is happening because you downloaded **"javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m09.jar"** this jar doesn't have ProcessingException download the latest one

```
Class not foundCaused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/ProcessingException
```

**Download this jar javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Secondly I think you are missing a part from your web.xml

Try adding these things to your web.xml as appropriate for you application. If you don't have this section this may also lead to **SEVERE: A child container failed during start....**

**This is what you are missing. Please note that param-value is the list of packages that contain your rest services.**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages;org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs</param-name>
        <param-value>com.your.package.for.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

**To get latest Jackson use this** [Link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider/2.3.3)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in eclipse. Just remove the libraries from Deployment Assembly and add them again. Sometimes after adding new jar does not update the library of the web application

**BuildPath**->**Deployment Assembly**